# Why is this causing an out of bounds error?

Tags: python, list, loops

So I'm working on a project right now and keep getting this error but I don't know what the problem is.

line 92, in play
    playerOne.append(pile[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

I don't understand what is causing it to be out of range. Here is my code. All the lists I'm using for startHand and pile have been defined above.

```
def play(startHand, pile):
playerOne = []
playerTwo = []

for i in range(0, 5):
    playerOne.append(startHand[i])
    i += 1

for i in range(5, 10):
    playerTwo.append(startHand[i])
    i += 1

initPoints = pile[0]

del pile[0]

if median(playerOne) == 9:
    scoreOne = initPoints
else:
    scoreOne = initPoints + median(playerOne)

if median(playerTwo) == 9:
    scoreTwo = initPoints
else:
    scoreTwo = initPoints + median(playerTwo)

playerOne.remove(median(playerOne))
playerTwo.remove(median(playerTwo))

playerOne.append(pile[0])
playerTwo.append(pile[1])

del pile[0]
del pile[0]

while scoreOne or scoreTwo < 99 or len(pile) > 0:
    if median(playerOne) == 9:
        scoreOne = scoreOne
    else:
        scoreOne = scoreOne + median(playerOne)

    if median(playerTwo) == 9:
        scoreTwo = scoreTwo
    else:
        scoreTwo = scoreTwo + median(playerTwo)

    playerOne.remove(median(playerOne))
    playerTwo.remove(median(playerTwo))

    playerOne.append(pile[0])
    playerTwo.append(pile[1])

    del pile[0]
    del pile[0]
```

If someone could please explain what is causing the error I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: TL;DR but `pile` is empty.

Comment: `pile` must be empty if that's the line causing it. You can't get the 0th element of an empty list.

Comment: Wouldn't the while len(pile) > 0 keep if from running then?

Comment: `scoreOne or scoreTwo < 99 or len(pile) > 0:` that's an OR condition, not AND... BTW it's wrong because you're not really comparing both scores to 99...

Comment: you want `while scoreOne < 99 and scoreTwo < 99 and pile:`

Comment: I want the loop to stop if the score is above 99 or pile has no more cards in it. How would i compare both to 99?

Comment: Wouldn't that only stop the loop if both scores were above 99 how would I get to stop for just one?

Answer (score 1):

```
while scoreOne or scoreTwo < 99 or len(pile) > 0:
```

that line is wrong, wrong, wrong:

- `scoreOne or scoreTwo < 99` is actually like `(scoreOne) or (scoreTwo < 99)`, so as long as `scoreOne` isn't zero, the `while` statement executes (even if `pile` is empty)
- even with a fix, you still use `or` statements, which means that `pile` *can* be empty as long as the scores are < 99.

What you want is

```
while scoreOne < 99 and scoreTwo < 99 and len(pile)>0:
```

or in a more pythonic way (testing empty list can be done by checking the "truthyness" of this list by testing just the list itself):

```
while scoreOne < 99 and scoreTwo < 99 and pile:
```

that *keeps your program in the loop* as long as both scores are below 99 and `pile` has something in it.

Comment: Thanks that did it so this may be a stupid question but why does the pile: thing work?

Comment: it's a shorthand for "list not empty".

Comment: @Dylan https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html - several things evaluate to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

> IndexError: list index out of range

It means your are accessing a list (f.e.) outside of the elements it has. Check the lists content and make sure it is not None.